# how to define unit vectors in mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, tensors, vector-calculus

I'm struggling a little bit trying to understand how to address this problem, I would like to do this in mathematica: [image: problem] is just that I don't know how to do the dot product between $\mathbf{J}$ and $\mathbf{a}_y$ because I don't know how to define the unit vector $\mathbf{a}_y$, is it possible to do this in mathematica? thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand what it's supposed to represent but maybe `UnitVector[1]` and `UnitVector[2]`? Or `UnitVector[3, 1]` etc.

Comment: `ax = {1, 0, 0}; ay = {0, 1,  0};`    `j = -10^4 Exp[-2 y] (Sin[2 x] ax + Cos[2 x] ay);`  
`Integrate[j.ay /. y -> 1, {z, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 1}] // N`

Comment: @LouisB Post it as an answer?

Comment: Guys thank you for all your help,@LouisB solution was easy and simple, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown by LouisB in the comment, use [coordinate vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_vector) is the standard way to go, nevertheless, it's possible to implement the symbolic coordinate bases as follows:

```
Clear[Subscript]
Subscript /: Subscript[a, x_]^2 = 1;
Subscript /: Subscript[a, x_] Subscript[a, y_] /; x =!= y = 0;
Subscript[a_, b : x | y | z] := Subscript[a, ToString@b]

J = -10^4  (Subscript[a, x] Sin[2 x] E^(-2 y) + Subscript[a, y] Cos[2 x] E^(-2 y)) 10^3
Integrate[J Subscript[a, y] /. y -> 1, {z, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 1}] // N
```

[image]

Or more rigorously:

```
Clear[Subscript]
Subscript /: Subscript[a, x_].Subscript[a, x_] = 1;
Subscript /: Subscript[a, x_].Subscript[a, y_] = 0;
Subscript[a_, b : x | y | z] := Subscript[a, ToString@b]

J = -10^4 (Subscript[a, x] Sin[2 x] E^(-2 y) + Subscript[a, y] Cos[2 x] E^(-2 y)) 10^3
Integrate[J.Subscript[a, y] /. y -> 1 // TensorExpand, {z, 0, 2}, {x, 0, 1}] // N
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @xzczd, in your code there are some things I still don't understand because I'm new using Mathematica but I will research and try to learn more, thank you for helping me out!